# To Pipe or Not to Pipe?

Tags: f#

That is (sort of) the question.

I'm trying to learn F# more lately and my resources seem to prefer piping in places where it's not clear a benefit exists. For example, given a function in curried form:

`f: a -> b -> c -> R`

I can call it by supplying all the arguments inline or pipe `c` in like so:

```
let r = f a b c 
let r = c |> f a b
```

But is there a cost or benefit or is it purely a stylistic preference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<s>There should be no cost.</s>

**UPDATE**

There **may be** some extra cost.
Sometimes an extra call is inserted, but some other times the compiler can optimize it avoiding the extra call.

I tested the following code:

```
let concat (a:string) (b:string) = System.String.Concat(a, b)

let f1 g a c = g a c
let f2 g a c = c |> g a

f1     concat "b" "c" \\ 00:00:33.8895616
f2     concat "b" "c" \\ 00:00:34.6051700
       concat "b" "c" \\ 00:00:35.0669532
"c" |> concat "b"     \\ 00:00:35.1948296
f1     (+)    "b" "c" \\ 00:00:35.4796687
f2     (+)    "b" "c" \\ 00:00:49.3227193
       (+)    "b" "c" \\ 00:00:35.0689207
"c" |> (+)    "b"     \\ 00:00:35.8214733
```

For each case I performed a billion calls (`1_000_000_000`) and those were the times. As you can see only calling `f2 (+) "b" "c"` was slower than the rest which may have something to do with (+) being an operator that uses SRTP.

Thanks to @PhillipCarter for clarifying.

---

The use of pipe helps with type inference:

```
let words = "many words".Split ' '

let wordsU1 = words |> Array.map (fun w -> w.ToUpper())  // ok
wordsU1 |> Seq.iter (printfn "words are %A") 

let wordsU2 = Array.map (fun w -> w.ToUpper()) words     // type annotation needed: (w:string)
Seq.iter (printfn "words are %A") wordsU2
```

The two calls to `Array.map` are equivalent but the second one complains that it does not know the type of `w`. That is because F# type inference mechanism works from left to right and in the second case `words` is after the lambda function.

It is also better stylistically. The code above can be better expressed like this:

```
"many words".Split ' '
|> Array.map (fun w -> w.ToUpper())
|> Seq.iter (printfn "words are %A")
```

So the pipe can be used to chain several expressions without having to use parenthesis or binding it to names.

Comment: Thanks for the clear example. I assume the more idiomatic way would be piping since we can avoid the type annotation. I'll have to go back and see if that was the author's reasoning.

Comment: There actually is a nonzero cost, but it's not likely to matter in most cases. The pipe option in @ChiefTwoPencils's question will introduce a `callvirt`. You can see the difference [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:DYLgZgzgNALiCWwoBMQGoA+B7ADgUwDsACAZQE8IY8BbAWAChqtkBXYPIgWSIF4GiBRdjCJgiAcyIBDIgCMiAY14Tpcxf0HDRAchUz5SnoqIYAfHrlA=).

Comment: @PhillipCarter Cannot see it. Won't both `x |> f |> g` and `g (f x)` compile to `g.Invoke(f.Invoke(x));`? They used to.

Comment: It depends. If it can, the compiler will use `InvokeFast` on a call that has up to 5 curried arguments passed directly. This results in emitting less IL and something that is marginally faster. It has existed for [at least 5 years](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blame/44c7e10ca432d8f245a6d8f8e0ec19ca8c72edaf/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fsi#L1538). But if single arguments are involved, or currying is used, then it is not applicable. You can see the difference in the link I gave in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe. Don Syme loves pipelines ([proof](https://youtu.be/26_W8MmUA60?t=1412)) :)

Also remember there are `||>` and `|||>` pipes as well.